# how to extract the records with same prefix in C++ map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Now, I only know there are several records with same prefix "head_" in one map.
How do I extract all these records if I do not know their exact keys in this map ?
Any idea?

Comment: Iterate over them. To find them efficiently, ask for `map.lower_bound("head_")` then iterate until you find first key that doesn't match.

Comment: @JerryCoffin How would you specify your argument for `equal_range` to give you everything prefixed with "head_"?

Comment: @Xarn: After some thought, I believe I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to iterate through the map. However, you can find your starting point efficiently by calling [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) with key equal to your desired prefix.

```
void extract_keys(const std::map<std::string, int>& some_map){
    auto iter = some_map.lower_bound("head_");

    while (iter->first.find("head_") == 0){
        //do things with key, value pair
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

The code above should work, but I admit I didn't test it. (Any errors should be trivially fixable)

Comment: I think I can use map.lower_bound("head_") and map.upper_bound("head_") to find the range.

Comment: @city No, you cannot. You could use `upper_bound("head_zzzzzzz")` if you can assume that the longest valid key won't contain more Zs than whatever string you use to search, but you will then have to iterate between these two iterators anyway.